# How to compute total time taken to complete a thread group in JMeter?

Tags: jmeter

I am looking to see if it's possible to easily compute the total time taken to complete a Thread Group. In my case, I have a thread with 100 concurrent users with 1 HTTP request. I would like to know how long did it take to complete requests from all 100 users.
I tried using Transaction controller with Aggregation Report but it doesn't seem to capture the value across all concurrent users.

Thanks,
J

Answer (score -1):

1. Add [tearDown Thread Group](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#tearDown_Thread_Group) to your Test Plan. It is executed after all thread groups so it is a good place to measure test duration.
2. Add [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) as a child of the tearDown Thread Group
3. Put the following [Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) code into "Script" area:

   ```
   def testStart = new Date(vars.get('TESTSTART.MS') as long)
   def testEnd = new Date()

   use(groovy.time.TimeCategory) {
       def duration = testEnd - testStart
       log.info("Test duration: ${duration.seconds}")
   }
   ```
4. Once test finishes you will see its duration in seconds in *jmeter.log* file.

   [image: Groovy JMeter Test Duration]

   You can also use `${duration.hours}`, `${duration.days}`, etc.

Comment: Thanks. Does the setup and tearDown run for every thread group? I have multiple thread groups in my test plan.

Comment: If I have multiple thread groups, is it possible to run the tearDown for every thread group completion. If not, how to capture time taken by each thread groups